# Chat Transcript not saving the 'Transferred File' info - Einstein bot Salesforce

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

As our customers are sharing the files, when an agent enables the 'Sharing File' option. Here, customer is expecting to get the shared file info to get attached to the transcript after they click on 'Save Transcript' button. I don't see this as an option in exisitng functionality and need suggestions to achieve this functionality.

Steps to reproduce :
Start a chat -> connect with Live Agent -> Request agent to share file -> agent will enables the 'File Transfer' option -> customer will upload the file -> end the chat -> click on 'Save Transcript' button -> in downloaded script, shared file info is be missing.

Thanks for anticipation.